# How to convert pandas DataFrame column names into one column

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have follow pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df)

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

I want to convert it into below format:

```
  field data
0     a    1
1     a    4
2     b    2
3     b    5
4     c    3
5     c    6
```

The original column name as the new colume `field` value, and the data is the original data of column, how to implement this?

Comment: `df.melt()` or `df.stack().reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `stack` the datframe, then perform some index drop/reset, and column renames:

```py
df.stack().droplevel(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'field', 0:'data'})
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
  field  data
0     a     1
1     b     2
2     c     3
3     a     4
4     b     5
5     c     6
```

Or you can just use `melt` method passing variable and value column names:

```py
>>> df.melt(var_name='field', value_name='data')

  field  data
0     a     1
1     a     4
2     b     2
3     b     5
4     c     3
5     c     6
```

The order of the values differ for stack and melt though.